# Is the Frobenius property invariant by Morita equivalence?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, fusion-categories, morita-equivalence

Kaplansky's sixth conjecture [Ka75] states that the dimension of a semisimple finite dimensional Hopf algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ is divisible by the dimension of its irreducible complex representations.

This property is extended as follows in [ENO11]: a spherical fusion category $\mathcal{C}$ (over $\mathbb{C}$) has the *Frobenius property* if for every simple object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ then $\frac{\mathrm{FPdim}(\mathcal{C})}{\mathrm{FPdim}(X)}$ is an algebraic integer. This paper concludes by asking whether there is a fusion category without the Frobenius property [ENO11, Question 1].

We proved in [BP22, Corollary 4.10] that the Frobenius property holds for every spherical fusion category (over $\mathbb{C}$) if and only if it is invariant by Morita equivalence. This leads to the following question:

**Question**: Is the Frobenius property invariant by Morita equivalence?

---

*References*

[Ka75] I. Kaplansky; *Bialgebras*, Lecture Notes in Mathematics. Department of Mathematics, University of Chicago (1975) iv+57 pp.
[ENO11] P. Etingof, D. Nikshych, and V. Ostrik; *Weakly group-theoretical and solvable fusion categories*, Adv. Math., 226 (2011), pp. 176–205.
[BP22] S. Burciu, S. Palcoux; *Structure constants, Isaacs property and Extended-Haagerup fusion categories*, arXiv:2210.13936